# Application of Separation of Variables

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following:

Construct a nontrivial harmonic function $x(x,y)$ with vanishing dirichlet condition in the strip $\Omega={(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0<y<1}$.  Let $u(x.y)=X(x)Y(y)$ and find the ODEs for X(x) and Y(y) that satisfy the boundary conditions.

In order to satisfy the B.C.'s I need $\Delta u=0$ for $(x,y) \in \Omega$ and $u=0$ on $\delta \Omega$.  The second condition implies that $Y(y)=0$ for $y=0$ and $y=1$.  Not sure go from here to continue constructing X(x) and Y(y).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug $u=X\,Y$ in the equation to get
$$
X''\,Y+X\,Y''=0\implies \frac{X''}{X}=-\frac{Y''}{Y}.
$$
The right hand side dependes only on $y$, while the left hand side deppends only on $x$. This is posible only if both are constant. Call this constant $\lambda$. Then get two equations, one for $X$ and one for $Y$, this last one with additional conditions:
$$
X''-\lambda\,x=0,\quad Y''+\lambda Y=0,\quad Y(0)=Y(1)=0.
$$
Observe that $\lambda$ is unknown.

Can you go on from here?

Comment: Okay applying the boundary conditions that $Y(0)=Y(1)=0$ gives me that $Y(y)=sin(\pi*y)$ and $\lambda=\pi ^2.$  Applying the value for $\lambda$ into the ode for $X$ gives me $X(x)=Ae^{\pi t}+Be^{- \pi t}$.  Do I need to solve for A and B explicitly to complete the problem or is this enough?  It does satisfy the dirichlet condition and is harmonic...

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary constants. But you are missing lots of solutions, corresponding to $\lambda=k^2\,\pi^2$, $k=1,2,3\dots$

Comment: Right, so functions are $X(x)=A e^{\pi k t}+B e^{\pi (-k) t}$ and $Y(y)=sin(k \pi y)$ for when $\lambda=k^2 \pi^2$.

Comment: Yes. And now you can take linear combinations.

Comment: Then is $u(x,y)$ just a sum over k of $X(x)Y(y)$?

Comment: Well, in principle the sum could go to $\infty$, but then you would run into convergence problems. But any finite sum of that type of solution is certainly a solution.

Comment: Okay, so I can just write $u(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{k} X(x)Y(y)$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k < \infty$, and this should be a proper construction of nontrivial harmonic functions that satisfy the problem.

Comment: Yes. I would write $X_kY_k$ to make clear  the dependence on $k$.